# From Azure Stream Analytics to Power Bi Desktop

Tags: azure, powerbi, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have done some research on my own, but cant seem to find a solution. We have an IoT solution in Azure. We are gathering real-time streaming data from sensors to Azure IoT HUB. This data is getting sent to Azure Stream Analytics and through Azure functions we will display the data in Power Bi. This works for us so far, but we want the real-time streaming data not only in browser mode but also in Power BI desktop. Since the desktop has way more functionalities this is important. Does anybody have any input on this?

We have tried what I described

Answer (score 0):

You need to output the data from Stream Analytics to some kind of data store, like Azure SQL Database, Cosmos DB, etc. Then you can connect your PowerBI Desktop to that datastore.